# React Route not rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm building a website and I'm having problems with some routes. Everything works fine on localhost. But then, as soon as I build the whole thing and send it to the cpanel, it does not work anymore and I get 404 page. I have some components with just scroll, this way it shows as if it was a SPA but I have one route that I specifically want to render in a new window because it's the gallery.

This is my mainComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Home from "./home";
import Gallery from "./gallery";
import "../App.css";
import Header from "./headerComponent";
import Footer from "./FooterComponent";
import Service from "./servicesComponent";
import Contact from "./ContactComponent";
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import BasicRows from "./galleryGrid";

class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/home" component={Home}>
            <Home />
            <Service />
            <Gallery />
            <Contact />
          </Route>

          <>
            <Route path="/gallery" component={BasicRows}>
              <BasicRows />
            </Route>
          </>

          <Redirect to="/home" />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

This is my App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Main from "./components/mainComponent";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Main />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

EDIT: Ok guys, I do understand what's going on. `BrowserRouter` is not actually sending anything to the server, it merely changes the URL without actually redirecting. So, to temporally fix my situation, I'm using `useHistory` to redirect my URL.

It's working now, but I'm going to set up a NodeJS/Express server so I don't have to go through this whole thing again.

Thanks y'all

```
let history = useHistory();

 <a className="button"
    id="galleryButton"
    onClick={() => history.push("/gallery")}
    >
    Gallery
 </a>
```

Comment: What is "cpanel"? Why is the gallery route in a React `Fragment`? Can you describe in greater detail what isn't working? Is the app nested in a subroute when you're not running it locally?

Comment: cpanel is the web hosting I'm using. I tried to say is, when i put the website live, do not work, but works in localhost. I honestly put a new react fragment, because that's how I thought i was supposed to do when I want a different route.

Comment: If your SPA isn't working on the server, it may be related to the webserver configuration. It might try to find an actual index.html in `/gallery` instead of falling back to your main `/index.html`. See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment

Comment: Yeah, or you can also provide a [basename](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string) prop to the router to match when it's deployed into a subdirectory on a host. `basename` is specifically for this purpose.

Comment: @DrewReese any chance you give a help on how to do this? Im reading the doc, but Im kind of confused.

Comment: `Router basename="/deployedsubdirectoryname">....`? Can you give us a little more insight as to where you are hosting your app and running it from?

Comment: I found a temp solution to make everything work, but if I write the path manually it's not gonna work. I dont think i can avoid the situation without putting a server to run, so that's what Im gonna do next.

Comment: It may be more conventional in RRD to render a `Link`, i.e. `<Link className="button" id="galleryButton" to="/gallery">Gallery</Link>`.